# c# print recursively by traversing tree

Tags: c#, .net, recursion, tree, tree-traversal

I am trying to traverse and print the following tree:

[image]

My intended result is:

```
State2
State2/State3
State2/State3/State4
```

Below is the code I am trying:

```
    public void EA_MenuClick(EA.Repository rep, string location, string menuName, string itemName)
        {
EA.Diagram diag;
                DiagramElement diagramElementsObj = new DiagramElement();
            char[] charsToReplaceFromDiagramId = new char[] { '{', '}' };
                            diag = rep.GetContextObject();

                            diagramElementsObj.refDiagramName = diag.Name;
                            diagramElementsObj.refDiagramId = diag.DiagramGUID.Trim(charsToReplaceFromDiagramId);

                            diagramElementsObj.states = new List<State>();
                            diagramElementsObj.transitions = new HashSet<Transition>();

                            foreach (EA.DiagramObject diagramObj in diag.DiagramObjects)
                            {
                                int elementId = diagramObj.ElementID;
                                EA.Element element = rep.GetElementByID(elementId);

                                State stateObj = new State();

                              
                                    if (element.MetaType == "State")
                                    {
                                        //stateObj.name = Utilities.FormatElementName(element.Name, rep, element);
                                        FormatElementName(element.Name, rep, element);
                                        stateObj.name = stateName;
                                        diagramElementsObj.states.Add(stateObj);
                                    }
                                

                                if (element.Methods.Count > 0)
                                {
                                    GetActionsByState(element, stateObj);
                                }
                                GetAllTransitions(rep, diagramElementsObj, element);
                            }
        }
```

Here **DiagramElement** is the parent class which has list of child called **State**. **State** has a **property** called **Name**. I am preparing the object in the above class. I don't know whether I can do it the below recursive method.

Below is the method for formatting:

```
public void FormatElementName(string result, EA.Repository rep, EA.Element element)
    {
        if (element.Elements.Count == 0)
        {
            stateName = result;
            return;
        }
        foreach (EA.Element child in element.Elements)
        {
            FormatElementName(result + "/" + child.Name, rep, child);
        }
    }
```

And getting the following output in the reverse order:

```
State2/State3/State4
State3/State4
State4
```

How can I reverse the order? I am using c#.

Comment: Unclear how/where you are printing things.

Comment: For an Enterprise Architect plugin. Assigning the names in an object and later converting it to yaml

Comment: Still unclear.how you cycle the rows. You make a single call. Even if `stateName` is a property of the class containing `FormatElementName`, at he end it will have a single value.

Comment: Please refer to the updated post

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you want something like this.

```
FormatElementName("", rep, element);

public void FormatElementName(string prefix, EA.Repository rep, EA.Element element)
{
   string result = prefix + element.Name;
   prefix = result + "/";

   State stateObj = new State();                                   
   stateObj.name = stateName;
   diagramElementsObj.states.Add(stateObj);    

   if (element.Elements.Count == 0)
   {    
       return;
   } 
   foreach (EA.Element child in element.Elements)
   {
       FormatElementName(prefix, rep, child);
   }
 }
```

Comment: I have added the full  method above for clarification. stateobj.name is assigned in the called method, not from the recursive method. Is it absolutely necessary? I am not sure about that. I have also checked with your provided method and it's returning the same tree which I was getting previously with and it looks as follows: - name: ==State2State2/State3/State4
 == State3State3/State4
 == State4State4

Comment: It is still unclear what result you try to achieve. As I understand you have `DiagramObjects` collection of root nodes, when you iterating it you create one state object for root node. If your goal is to create state object for each node deep in the tree, you have to put state instanciation and addition to `diagramElementsObj.states` into recursive method. And dont forget about empty initial prefix string.

Answer (score 0):

Below is the code for the solution:

```
public void GetStateName(string result, EA.Repository rep, EA.Element element)
        {
            if (element.ParentID == 0)
            {
                stateName = result;
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                EA.Element parent = rep.GetElementByID(element.ParentID);
                GetStateName(parent.Name + "/" + result, rep, parent);
            }
        }
```